# How can I draw the table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

[image]

How can I draw the table in LaTeX? Particularly the content bottom of the table?

Comment: I suggest using `matrix` library of TikZ. What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: For arrow  with label below table you can use `tikzmark` library.

Answer (score 10):

You can do that with an ordinary array and `pstricks`: I defined the last elements in columns  5 and 8 as `\rnode`s and connected with the relevant node connection. Note that the pstricks part of the code, used this way, has no  dimension for latex, so  I added a supplementary row containing only a vertical space, to prevent any overlapping with the following text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[semibold, condensed]{cabin}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{array}{ |*{8}{c|}}
\hline
\bm{A} & \bm{B} & \bm{C} & \bm{B\cap C}& \bm{A \cup ∪ (B \cap C)}& \bm{A \cup B}& \bm{A \cup C}& \bm{(A \cup B)\cap(A \cup C)} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \rnode{A}{1} & 1 & 1 & \rnode{B}{1} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\vspace{4ex}}%
\ncbar[linewidth=0.6pt, arrows=<->, arrowinset=0.12,angle=-90, nodesep=1.5ex]{A}{B}
\nbput{\sffamily\bfseries\small \Shortunderstack{Since these columns are identical, we conclude \\%
 that $\;\bm{A\cup(B\cap C)=(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)}$}}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (+1)! How you type unicode symbols ∪ and ∩? Using WinEdt so far I didn't find them at my keyboard.

Comment: Zarko: I should have checked the code. Initially, I typed the usual latex  commands, but actually, my version of WinEdt  uses a macro that saves symbols or Greek letters as the corresponding latex commands, but displays them as the symbols, to make the code more readable, mathematically. I'll fix that  within seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for info. Onence I need to look in my WinEdt settings and macros and refresh my understanding of unicode (how to simple access symbols by keys in keyboard). Maybe over holidays ...

Comment: If you're interested, I'm the author of the `MathGreek` configuration component on WinEdt.org

Comment: Good to know.  I'm interested, of course. Thank you. I will look there ASAP.

Comment: The second `A` in the note at the bottom should surely be a `B`...

Comment: @Thruston: Still another of my copy-paste accidents. I definitely should check everything before posting… I'll fix that in a moment. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 7):

Let me extend my comment to answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{ |*{8}{c|}}
    \hline
\bm{A} & \bm{B} & \bm{C} & \bm{B\cap C}& \bm{A\cup (B\cap C)}
    & \bm{A\cup B} & \bm{A\cup C} & \bm{(A\cup B)\cap (A \cup C)} \\
    \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \tikzmarknode{a}{1} 
                  & 1 & 1 & \tikzmarknode{b}{1} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\vspace{4\baselineskip} % <--- space for arrow
\tikz[>=Straight Barb, overlay,remember picture]%
{
\draw[<->, semithick, shorten <=2ex, shorten >=2ex]
    (a) -- ++ (0,-1) -|
    node[align=center,font=\bfseries, pos=0.25, below]
        {Since these columns are identical, we conclude \\%
         that $\;\bm{A\cup(A\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)}$}
                        (b); 
}
\]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]